# How can I get product image from REST API as HTTPS

Tags: magento2, url, rest-api, https, media-images

I use `V1/getproductimage/<sku>` and get product's image url from API. It returns

```
[
    {
        "product_image_url": "http://<host>/pub/media/catalog/product/cache/36e9cda53c678653975daba9a022fb1d/<media file>"
    }
]
```

I'm developing LINE chatbot, It need HTTPS URL to be action in LINE FLEX. So, I want to know how can I get product image from REST API as HTTPS. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't anything  specific  to API that  you  need to do. Just make sure that the **"Secure Base URL for Static View Files"** under **Stores > Settings > Configuration > Web** is properly  configured  to use https.

Answer (score 0):

/V1/products?searchCriteria[pageSize]=20

Modify the API url like above code fragment. You will get all details about the products where you can also find image path too.